# How to scroll the key maps list?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, scrolling

When I was testing out the [Archlinux Ultimate Install](https://github.com/helmuthdu/aui) script I got stuck with a fairly silly problem.

I've this list with key maps and I have to select one.

[image: Keymaps]

How can I scroll this list in the situation, which the screenshot indicates, so I can find the right number?

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Have you tried Shift+Page Up?

Comment: @Larssend: That actually works! Thank you so much! Maybe you want to post it as an answer? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Page Down</kbd> to scroll up and down in a TTY/console.